# Binet's Formula Proof (Einstein notation, Levi-Civita symbol)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm trying to understand the proof below... Although I'm familiar with the notation itself, I'm in trouble with the underlined statement... can anyone explain? [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit confusing offhand because, after all, in the original sum $l_1,\dots,l_n$ needn't even be distinct. But let's consider a simpler example. Take $n=2$ and let's look at two cases. When $l_1=l_2=1$,
$$b_{l_1k_1}b_{l_2k_2}\epsilon_{k_1k_2} = b_{11}b_{12} - b_{12}b_{11} = 0;$$
the terms cancel because we can interchange $k_1$ and $k_2$ without changing the product.  When $l_1$ and $l_2$ are distinct, we have either
$$b_{1k_1}b_{2k_2}\epsilon_{k_1k_2}\quad\text{or}\quad b_{2k_1}b_{1k_2}\epsilon_{k_1k_2};$$
to turn the second sum into the first, we must interchange $k_1$ and $k_2$, so these sums differ by a factor $-1 = \epsilon_{21}$.

The general case is conceptually the same, just a bit messier to say. You first show that when any of the $l_i$ duplicate, the sum is $0$. You next show that when you permute $l_1,\dots,l_n$, the sums differ by the sign of that permutation.

Comment: While waiting for an answer I made some progress, I guess.. maybe related to your answer. I say that [$b_{l_1k_1}b_{l_2k_2}...b_{l_nk_n} \epsilon_{k_1k_2...k_n} = \det{B}$] only if ($l_1, l_2, ..., l_n$) are not all the same.

Comment: To assure it I can add $\epsilon_{l_1l_2...l_n}$ which remove that possibility. However that term add a sign in the expression that correspond to the sign of permutation ($l_1, l_2, ..., l_n$).

Comment: In that case I stay with: [$a_{1l_1}a_{2l_2}...a_{nl_n} \epsilon_{l_1l_2...l_n} \cdot b_{l_1k_1}b_{l_2k_2}...b_{l_nk_n} \epsilon_{k_1k_2...k_n} =\det{A} \cdot \det{B}$].

Comment: But this is not the original expression anymore: [$\det(AB) = a_{1l_1}a_{2l_2}...a_{nl_n} \cdot b_{l_1k_1}b_{l_2k_2}...b_{l_nk_n} \epsilon_{k_1k_2...k_n}$] due to that supplementary sign, am I right? How can I resolve this last problem, in general?

Comment: No, this is precisely the correct formula. As I showed in my example, you have precisely the equality in the second equation (not the red underlined part, but the whole equation).

Comment: So, would you say that the path I was following in the second comment of mine was wrong? Thus I should follow a case-by-case generalization starting from 2D?

Comment: Forget the $a$'s and prove the second displayed equation as I suggested. Then put the $a$'s back and you have the formula. Your first comment is incorrect, I think. We are fixing $l_1,\dots,l_n$, so we do not get the determinant of $B$ unless you correct. But we don't need the determinant of $B$ here.